# in a classification problem, why F1-score is more suitable than accuracy when the classes are unbalanced?

Tags: machine-learning

i understand that F1 score is more important if the false positive/false negative are crucial to determine a good classifier. i read in a site that ***"F1 Score is the weighted average of Precision and Recall; therefore, this score takes both false positives and false negatives into account. Intuitively it is not as easy to understand as accuracy, but F1 is usually more useful than accuracy, especially if you have an uneven class distribution***". the fact the F1 score is more suitable for uneven or unbalanced class was written also in other sites, but what is the reason about this condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lets say you have class A = 1000 and class B = 100, 
Here when you use accuracy as a evaluation metrics.
where,

```
Accuracy = Correct Predictions for class A  + Class B / Total Predictions
```

lets say out of 1000 from class A , correct prediction is 950 and for class B , correct predictions are 10 out of 100.
Then as per the accuracy formula,

```
Accuracy = 950 (class A correct predictions) + 10 (class B correct predictions) / 1100

Accuracy  = 0.8727272727272727 (87%)
```

In this imbalanced case we got 87% accuracy which is good but if you noticed for class B we only predicted 10 records correctly out of 100, which means our model is not able to predict class B but Accuracy metric shows our model is very good (87%) accuracy.
So for this case we use f1-score which handle evaluation of imbalanced problem.

```
F1 = 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)
```

f1-score takes precision and recall into consideration hence it is important to evaluate model with f1-score in case of imbalance data or else if you still want to use accuracy as a matrix use with class wise accuracy like accuracy for class A and accuracy for class B.

Answer (score 0):

I argue in this reply that, F1 is NOT a better metric than accuracy (even in case where we have an uneven class distribution). It is better to use class-wise accuracy than F1, for uneven class distributions as a metric.

I use the same example as [outlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60091206/12716510): We have class A = 1000 and class B = 100

Predictor 1: Lets say out of 1000 from class A , correct prediction is 950 and for class B , correct predictions are 10 out of 100

Predictor 2: Lets say out of 1000 from class A , correct prediction is 870 and for class B , correct predictions are 90 out of 100

**Central point of the argument:** If F1 were to be better metric than accuracy for uneven class distribution, then it is reasonable to expect F1 score to be lower for a predictor with poor scarce class accuracy (10% - predictor 1) as compared to predictor with good scarce class accuracy (90% - predictor 2)

However observation of F1 scores of Predictor 1 & Predictor 2 from [Table of metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGpsC.png), shows that F1 score of a predcitor (Predictor 1) with poor scarce class accuracy is greater than predictor (Predictor 2) with good scarce class accuracy

Notice how class-wise accuracy is better as a metric for uneven class dstribution